# xcode 7 cannot assign a value of type '[NSHTTPCookie]' to a value of type '[NSHTTPCookie]'

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

I just updated to Xcode7 and am trying to switch my project to using the Swift 2.0 Syntax when I ran into this error in a file from an open source library I'm using. Here's the relevant code:

```
public lazy var cookies:[String:NSHTTPCookie] = {
    let foundCookies: [NSHTTPCookie]
    if let responseHeaders = (self.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.allHeaderFields {
        foundCookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(responseHeaders, forURL:NSURL(string:"")!) as! [NSHTTPCookie]
    } else {
        foundCookies = []
    }
    var result:[String:NSHTTPCookie] = [:]
    for cookie in foundCookies {
        result[cookie.name] = cookie
    }
    return result
    }()
```

The error reads: Cannot assign a value of type '[NSHTTPCookie]' to a value of type '[NSHTTPCookie]'

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
public lazy var cookies:[String:NSHTTPCookie] = {
  let foundCookies: [NSHTTPCookie]
  if let responseHeaders = (self.response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.allHeaderFields as? [String:String] {
    foundCookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(responseHeaders, forURL:NSURL(string:"")!)
  } else {
    foundCookies = []
  }
  var result:[String:NSHTTPCookie] = [:]
  for cookie in foundCookies {
    result[cookie.name] = cookie
  }
  return result
  }()
```

Changes:

- `if let responseHeaders ...` line - did add `as? [String:String]`, because `allHeadersFields` return type is `[NSObject : AnyObject]` and not `[String:String`] required by `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields...`
- removed `as! [NSHTTPCookie]` - it has no sense, because `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields` return type is already `[NSHTTPCookie]`

Just check `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields` signature:

```
class func cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(headerFields: [String : String],
  forURL URL: NSURL) -> [NSHTTPCookie]
```

Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). At least, you should point out to lines where the problem is, etc.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Apologies for not pointing out the specific line, and thanks for the reference.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember - more info about your problem provided (even if you think it's not important), quicker working answer without additional questions.