# NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields

Tags: swift2, nshttpcookie, nshttpurlresponse

When making a call to an API, I receive this as response:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7f96f0510f80> { URL: https://insula.magister.net/api/sessie } { status code: 201, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "max-age=120, private";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Thu, 30 Jul 2015 17:27:11 GMT";
    "Set-Cookie" = "SESSION_ID=c8714acb-22f8-4295-90ee-82e9469890e1; domain=insula.magister.net; path=/api; secure; httponly";
    "Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=31536000";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding,Cookie";
    "X-Frame-Options" = DENY;
} }
```

`print(HTTPResponse.allHeaderFiles)` prints the following output:

```
[Set-Cookie: SESSION_ID=65a59001-de75-41ff-ad22-70549baa96f5; domain=insula.magister.net; path=/api; secure; httponly, Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000, Date: Thu, 30 Jul 2015 17:33:13 GMT, X-Frame-Options: DENY, Content-Length: 0, Cache-Control: max-age=120, private, Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie]
```

But I can't get `cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields` to work, I should pass a `[String:String]` array as first parameter, but the response doesn't seem to meet.

`let cookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(HTTPResponse.allHeaderFields, forURL: url)`

But as `HTTPResponse.allHeaderFiles` is an array of type `[NSObject:AnyObject]` it can't meet the `[String:String]` parameter type.
Who knows what to do?

Answer (score 2):

There's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385472/xcode-7-cannot-assign-a-value-of-type-nshttpcookie-to-a-value-of-type-nsht) with a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31385849/758990).

You should cast the `allHeaderFields` property to the type you need, that is `[String:String]`, like this:

```
  let foundCookies: [NSHTTPCookie]?
  if let responseHeaders = HTTPResponse.allHeaderFields as? [String:String] {
    foundCookies = NSHTTPCookie.cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields(responseHeaders, forURL:url)
  }
```